# How to manipulate search functionality of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How to replace `s` with `search` in core search functionality of Wordpress for search query?

Already tried in `general-template.php`.

It didn't work out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suggest don't tweak the core WP, since you will lose your tweak if you update WP.